# Are there any plans to support DITA in keystonejs?

Tags: content-management-system, keystonejs, dita

Could anybody please share any plans to support the [DITA](http://dita.xml.org/standard) standard in keystonejs. This standard has become the de facto for many organizations looking to use ECMS and CCMS systems. Per the home page "DITA defines an XML architecture for designing, writing, managing, and publishing many kinds of information in print and on the Web".

Comment: I know of no one doing this but it's an interesting idea. It is not being done or being officially discussed by the DITA Technical Committee (I'm a member). Keystone JS might be a good application for the upcoming Lightweight DITA: https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=dita-lightweight-dita

Comment: Although if I understood correctly, that keystonejs is just web application platform, it would be quite interesting to see how DITA could bend for this. I would say that some industries could find this idea quite interesting and some might even try it for delivering for example online manuals to their customers.

Comment: @markg thanks for the feedback. Not sure how a feature request would be filled but this is indeed important for a CCMS which I believe KeystoneJS could make a difference. While there are commercial offerings, there is not DITA compliant open source option other than Cinnamon Server which is written in Java. The demand for DITA comes out of vendor unlocking efforts and having CCMS capabilities to introduce embedded CMS functionality in a any product out there, avoiding that way sub-par integration efforts.

Comment: @barbwire Keystone is marketed as a "Node.js CMS & Web Application Platform"

Comment: @NestorUrquiza The DITA Technical Committee (the DITA standard body) would not try to do something with Keystone JS because they do not get into the tools side of things. Maybe you should try to implement it yourself.

Comment: @markg thanks again for the feedback. Indeed, I am hoping this will be the channel where KeystoneJS developers will look into to opine if this will make a good feature request for the product. They are not accepting this kind of requests in github issues section which is even hidden from the landing page. They point to stackoverflow for any non-bug related questions. I tagged this question as keystonejs and additionally as CMS and DITA because it relates to it. I am hoping they will chime in ;-) Thanks!